# Adding clickable arrow to dropdown select

Tags: html, css

I have added select tag but not able to correctly align the arrow inside the select area.It is aligned ouside the select area. Not able to click the arrow also.

Any wrong in the CSS I applied.

```css
.custom-selection select {
  border:none;
  background-color:white;
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  margin: 0;      
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
.custom-selection option{
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.custom-selection::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color:blue;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-selection:hover::before {
  color:white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.custom-selection::after {
  content: "\25bc"; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-selection">
  <select class="round" id="myselect">

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add some "px or %" here As I made :`.custom-selection::after {
    content: "\25bc";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 15px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, left, top or bottom need to be specified with a unit... Css cannot decide for you:

Problem was in class: `.custom-selection::after`. It was more complex than basic question, please check comment to get them all.

DEMO:

```js
$("#myselect").on("click", function() {
  if($('.custom-selection.rotate').length > 0){
    $('.custom-selection').removeClass('rotate');
  }
  else{
    $('.custom-selection').addClass('rotate');
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:red;
}
.custom-selection{
  position:relative;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.custom-selection select {
  border:none;
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  margin: 0;      
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.custom-selection option{
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.custom-selection::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color:blue;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  display:block;
  z-index:1;
}

.custom-selection:hover::before {
  color:white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.custom-selection::after {
  content: "\25bc"; 
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 9px);
  right: 15px;
  background-color:white;
}
.custom-selection.rotate::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-selection">
  <select class="round" id="myselect">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have to click under the score and choose one as a solution. The arrow just show that the answer helped you or seems to be the good solution

Comment: Sorry, I was not following that. Yes you can use js / Jquery

Comment: But I added arrow using ```content: "\25bc"```..How can I add onclick to that!!

Comment: @kavya Here I made with jQuery Just add/Remove a class with `custom-selection` and it make the job

Comment: Yes..on arrow click why it is not responding? only when I click selection box it triggers

Comment: Because as it is not part of the select, it is consider as another object. as the select

Comment: Sure you can, you need to make your div with same length as select with position relative and then add position aboslute to select with background transparent. I can show you if you want

Comment: Can i try use `z-index` ?

Comment: If you make with z-index, you will still need to make the background :transparetn, but sure, it might work

Comment: @kavya Here you go. Enjoy 2nd Demo

Comment: @MaxiGui you can add z-index in first demo too. :)

Comment: Sure but actualy I let it this way because I have some customers (still wonder why) that prefer having it this way

Answer (score 2):

I had done, `position: absolute; float:right` to set content on right, and `margin-left: -1.5em` to move relatively and `margin-top: 0.75em` same as to move slightly down.

If we use px then its output on mobile or tablet may differ, but here I had used em instead of px. well em and rem mostly used in changing fonts size.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .custom-selection select {
            border:none;
        background-color:white;
        color: blue;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
        margin: 0;      
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        }
        .custom-selection option{
            border-radius: 18px;
        }

        .custom-selection::before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 28px;
        color:blue;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        pointer-events: none;
        }

        .custom-selection:hover::before {
        color:white;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }
        .custom-selection::after {
        content: "\25bc"; 
        /* changes required it works with any view port*/
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        margin-left: -1.5em;
        margin-top: 0.75em;
        /* end  */
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-selection">
        <select class="round" id="myselect">
             <option value="Rajkot">Rajkot</option>
             <option value="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
             <option value="Surat">Surat</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you've done to fix the problem, please?

Comment: I had done, position: absolute, float:right to set content on right, and margin-left: -1.5em to move relatively and margin-top: 0.75em same as to move slightly down. If we use px then its output on mobile or tablet may differ, but here I had used em instead of px. well em and rem mostly used in changing fonts size,.... highlighted comments on code that's only require to change.